# How to draw inner circle that moves in Bootstrap Carousel's indicator using CSS?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, indicator

How to draw inner circle that moves in Bootstrap Carousel's indicator using CSS?

It looks as following:

[image]

[image]

And hover needs to be as following:

[image]

The code I wrote so far looks as following:

```
<style lang="sass">
.carousel-indicators li
  background-color: transparent
  border: 0
  border-radius: 100%
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
  height: 22px
  margin-left: 15px
  margin-right: 15px
  width: 22px
.carousel-indicators li:hover
  background-color: #fff
  border: 0
  border-radius: 100%
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
  height: 22px
  margin-left: 15px
  margin-right: 15px
  width: 22px
</style>
```

Comment: In boostrap we can use icons instead https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/record/ and https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/record2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pseudo-elements` to do so.

First target the `li`, which also as the unactive state:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Now to create `border` use `pseudo-elements`:

```
.carousel-indicators li:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  right: -7px;
}
```

We have assign background `transparent` to the `li`, but we want background `white` in the `active` state so,

```
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/abmRbZv